# How to parse JSON with single quotes with JSONModel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, jsonmodel

Is there any way to parse JSON with single quotes like

```
{'lat': 0, 'lng': 0}
```

with `JSONModel`?

Comment: No. That's not JSON. JSON uses `"` exclusively. If somethign doesn't follow the strict JSON syntax requirements, then it's not JSON. That's basically just Javascript.

Comment: @MarcB I know, but for example `google-gson` does this, and who knows, may be `JSONModel` can do this too.

Comment: @mixel MarcB is hitting the nail (in the comment below as well). There's no easy way to make this JSON. Period. Talk to the guys who produced it and try to sell it as JSON and kindly ask to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up with @CouchDeveloper advice.

Answer (score 1):

you could replace the wrong chars:

```
NSString *json = [yourJSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\""];
```

and then you can handle it as corretc JSON :-)

Comment: It's obvious answer :)

Comment: As long as there's no embedded/escaped quotes, e.g. `{'foo':'bar\'baz'}` or `{'foo':'bar"baz'}`. both are valid JS, but the second one will be corrupted if you do a blind replacement, and the first one may have differnt meaning because you've changed content, not scaffolding.

Comment: of course... best way would be to produce correct json data, but even with replacing you could grain down the find and replace to each word inside the whole json und make sure, that you replace the incorrect characters only...